# Proof that $\log(a^b) = b\log a$ when $\log$ is defined by an integral

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms

When $\log a$ is defined as $\displaystyle\int_1^a\frac{dx}x$, then how does one prove that $\log(a^b)=b\log a$?

**I will post an answer here that is identical to an answer I posted to another question.  The original poster down-voted it saying that's not the definition of logarithm he was using.**

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative proof**

Let

$$F(a)=\int_1^{a^b}\frac{dx}{x}$$
then by the fundemental theorem of analysis
$$F'(a)=\frac{1}{a^b}\times ba^{b-1}=\frac ba$$
so we integrate  we find

$$F(a)=b\log a+C$$
and using that $F(1)=0$ we conclude that
$$F(a)=\log(a^b)=b\log  a$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\log(a^b) = \int_1^{a^b} \frac{dx}x.
$$
Suppose $w^{\,b}=x$.  Then $bw^{b-1}\,dw= dx$, so $b\dfrac{dw}{w} = \dfrac{dx}x$.  As $x$ goes from $1$ to $a^b$, then $w$ goes from $1$ to $a$.  Hence,
$$
\log(a^b) = \int_1^{a^b} \frac{dx}x = \int_1^a b \frac{dw}w = b\log a.
$$

Comment: If $b$ is rational, there's no need to prove $(d/dw)w^b=bw^{b-1}$ by using logarithms and the chain rule.  Might some circularity arise in case $b$ is irrational?  I think one might prove the "power rule" by squeezing, so maybe not.

Comment: (I can readily answer the question in my previous comment when I'm not busy with anything else.  Maybe I'll do that tomorrow.)

Comment: The derivative rule for irrational $b$ can be established using the generalized binomial theorem $(x+h)^b=x^b+bx^{b-1}h+\frac{b(b-1)}2x^{b-2}h^2...$

Comment: @YvesDaoust : But it might take more work to prove the generalized binomial theorem than to demonstrate the power rule by other methods.